# Facebook Social Publisher stopped publishing to timeline with message about enabling explicit sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I've been publishing to my timeline and to a page without issue, but now when i publish it will go to the page, but not to the timeline.

When I publish the post I get this error

> Failed posting to your Facebook Timeline. Error: {"message":"(#100) You haven't enabled Explicitly Shared for this action type (331247406956072) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard","type":"OAuthException"}

The OG setting for the post is Article

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dane Morgan">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="133706573436103">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.danemorgan.com/freelanceer/pain-message/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Pain and Gain | Pain is a Message, Gain is a Response">
<meta property="og:description" content="Pain and Gain, Real or imagined?
```

I have an associated Open Graph action-object pair: people can publish an article in the Open Graph -> types section of the app.

I can't find anything that isn't set the way the instructions in the plugin direct, and other tan updating the site to WP 3.6 I can't think of any changes that would have caused this to stop working.

I went in to the publish type and set explicitly shared which the plugin seems to be suggestion, though I'm not clear whether as an option or as a requirement. his resulted in a new error message:

> Failed posting to your Facebook Timeline. Error: {"message":"Object at URL 'http://www.danemorgan.com/blogging/test-post-time-line/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '{794463625}' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.","type":"Exception"}

The control says that review is required for anyone to use it, but that Admins can use it, and I only intend myself to use it as this is a single author blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual FB continuously make changes without take care about us >:

1) In your app page: Open Graph > Action Types > Add Action type.
2) Write "Publish" and save.
3) Go down to "Capabilities" and check "Explicitly Shared".

[image]
[image]